# For loop using grepl

Tags: r, for-loop, grepl, nested-for-loop

### Example Data

I'm writing a script with the intent to copy input files, each to multiple locations. Below is an example of functional code to achieve this:

```
##### File 1 #####
output_paths_1 <- list(c(paste0(path_1, "file_1", ".xlsx"),
                         paste0(path_2, "file_1", ".xlsx"),
                         paste0(path_3, "file_1", " ", gsub("-", "", Sys.Date()), ".xlsx")))

lapply(output_paths_1, function (x) file.copy(paste0(input_path, "input_1.xlsx"), x, overwrite = T))

##### File 2 #####
output_paths_2 <- list(c(paste0(path_1, "file_2", ".xlsx"),
                         paste0(path_2, "file_2", ".xlsx"),
                         paste0(path_3, "file_2", " ", gsub("-", "", Sys.Date()), ".xlsx")))

lapply(output_paths_2, function (x) file.copy(paste0(input_path, "input_2.xlsx"), x, overwrite = T))

##### File 3 #####
output_paths_3 <- list(c(paste0(path_1, "file_3", ".xlsx"),
                         paste0(path_2, "file_3", ".xlsx"),
                         paste0(path_3, "file_3", " ", gsub("-", "", Sys.Date()), ".xlsx")))

lapply(output_paths_3, function (x) file.copy(paste0(input_path, "input_3.xlsx"), x, overwrite = T))
```

---

### Reprex

But I suspect there are more efficient methods. In my latest attempt, which does not work, I used a nested 'for' loop. I create data frames containing each input and file name. Then (in theory), for each `i` in `inputs`, I write an `output paths` data frame for each `i` in `files`. I filter this data frame for only one file at a time using `grepl`. See code below:

```
files <- data.frame(data = c("file_1", "file_2", "file_3"))
inputs <- data.frame(data = c("input_1.xlsx", "input_2.xlsx", "input_3.xlsx"))

for (i in seq_along(inputs)) {
  for (i in seq_along(files)) {
    output_paths <- data.frame(data = c(paste0(path_1, files[[i]], ".xlsx"),
                                        paste0(path_2, files[[i]], ".xlsx"),
                                        paste0(path_3, files[[i]], " ", gsub("-", "", Sys.Date()), ".xlsx"))) %>%
      filter(grepl(files[[i]], `data`))
    lapply(output_paths, function (x) file.copy(paste0(input_path, inputs[[i]]), x, overwrite = T))
    }
}
```

I expected this to copy the first file to three locations, then the next file to those same locations, etc. Instead, the following Warning appears, and only the first file is copied to the desired locations:

```
Warning message:
In grepl(files[[i]], data) :
  argument 'pattern' has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Running the code *without* including the `grepl` function does nothing at all - no files are copied to the desired locations.

---

### Questions:

1. How might I tweak the code above to iterate for all elements, instead of the first element only?
2. Is there a more elegant approach entirely? (just looking for pointers, not reprex necessarily)

---

Comment: In your nested for loops, you are assigning `i` as `seq_along(inputs)` and then overwriting the same `i` as `seq_along(files)`. You need to assign a different vector for each loop. E.g., assign `j` as `seq_along(files)` and change all `files[[i]]` to `files[[j]]`. That might resolve your issue (I haven't tried yet).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish with your "Reprex" approach. But if you want to do what your first but of code does by writing less code, then you could do something like

```
files  = c("file1", "file2", "file3") # file names
opaths = c("path1", "path2", "path3") # output paths

df = expand.grid(file = files, path = opaths, stringsAsFactors = F)

df$from = file.path(input_path, df$file)
df$to   = file.path(df$path, df$file)

file.copy(from = df$from, to = df$to)
```

If you want the timestamp in the file name for path3, you could then do something like

```
df$to[df$path == "path3"] <- file.path(df$path[df$path == "path3"], 
                                       paste0(format(Sys.Date(), "%Y%m%d_"), df$file[df$path == "path3"])
                                       )
```

Comment: One issue with this option is that I have to rename the files once they've been moved. So in this example, I would need to include a third vector in the data frame, maybe `source = c("name1", "name2", name3")`, and use the resulting column to write the input path instead of `df$file`.